# installing ubuntu - getting stuck on splash screen on restart after installation. boot repair not working!

Tags: boot, system-installation, 22.04, boot-repair

complete noob here.

i'm trying to install the latest ubuntu desktop (22.04.2), but once it installs and requires the restart, it gets stuck on the manufacturer's splash screen (with no ubuntu logo) and freezes.

after having tried a dozen different things, i've tried to [follow the instructions here using boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) using the live session. [here is the pastebin report it generated](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Rxgn2pqhRH/). i tried the recommended repairs but it told me `The nvme0n1p3 (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS) partition is nearly full`, but there are no files on my computer (aside from windows 11 which i have backed up on an external drive and i'm not sure if windows is still on my computer anymore lol...). i'm completely lost!

**edit:** probably should mention i installed openSUSE before trying Ubuntu, so that's on the pastebin too.

**specs:**

- Lenovo ThinkPad
- Intel Celeron(R) N4020 CPU @ 1.10GHz × 2
- Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 600 (GLK 2)
- [IDK what else is relevant]

**update:** it was a problem with the partitions. using the live install i deleted them all except the one used as a system drive, reinstalled and it worked!

Comment: Minor correction: 22.04 is the latest **LTS** Ubuntu Desktop, but it's not the latest release of Ubuntu Desktop. There have been more two releases (22.10 and 23.04) since, and yet another (23.10) currently in pre-release testing. You were wise to specify the release number.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at parts of your boot-info output:

```
OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on nvme0n1p3

[...and...]

fdisk -l (filtered):
             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p3  1533952  21065727  19531776   9.3G Linux filesystem

[...and...]

Mount points (filtered):
/dev/nvme0n1p3                                                  247M  92% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3

[...also...]

nvme0n1p4 21065728 250068991 229003264 109.2G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p4                                                101.4G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
```

Your Ubuntu system is on a tiny 9.3G partition, and that partition is 92% full. The minimum recommended size is 25G.

Meanwhile, you also have a 101.4G partition that is completely empty.

The simplest solution is to reinstall, and to edit your partitions during the reinstall to meet the recommended size requirements.

Suggestion: The Ubuntu installer has sane defaults, and those defaults are good for most new users.